# Safe $variable binding in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Supposing I want to query for the XPath `//*[@id=$href]`. How can I tell nokogiri to safely bind a value for the `$href` variable?

This is similar to REXML's `XPath.first( node, "//*[@id=$href]", nil, {"href"=>"linktohere"})`

Comment: I've submitted a feature request at http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues#issue/329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has just (a half hour ago) been added to Nokogiri, so it should appear in the next version.

Comment: Nokogiri 1.4.4 now supports XPath variable binding.